# Is it possible to execute a Parallel.For loop starting max value, then decrementing

Tags: c#, for-loop, parallel-processing

is it possible to parallelize a for loop starting the max value, then decrement ? In the Parallel.For signature, it seems to be only the case when "i" increments

```
for (int i = Int32.MaxValue; i >= 0; --i)
{
    // do something...
}
```

Regards,

Florian

Comment: You could have: `x = max - i`

Comment: Did you try this for yourself ?  It's not something I've wanted to do, but if I did, I wouldn't waste my time asking about it on SO, I'd crash on and see what happened.

Comment: Well, the iterations will (possibly and hopefully) run **in parallel**, so if the order is important (increasing order or decreasing order), maybe you shouldn't use `Parallel.For`? Other than that, pst's idea is good.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It should not matter if you are writing parallel code:

[MSFT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff963552.aspx) does not guarantee that the loop will run from low to high, or in any particular order.

> Note:
>   The Parallel.For method does not guarantee any particular order of execution. Unlike a sequential loop, some higher-valued indices may be processed before some lower-valued indices.

In practice, Parallel.For absolutely **does not** run in order.

Consider Jeppe Stig Nielsen's example (from comments):

```
System.Threading.Tasks.Parallel.For(0, 25, i => { Console.WriteLine(i); });
```

On my machine with 4 cores, I got the following output:

> 0
>   1
>   2
>   4
>   5
>   7
>   8
>   10
>   11
>   12
>   13
>   14
>   15
>   16
>   17
>   18
>   19
>   20
>   21
>   22
>   23
>   24
>   3
>   9
>   6

Clearly the loop is not in order.

Comment: Exactly. As an easy demonstration, the Original Poster could try this example: `Parallel.For(0, 25, i => { Console.WriteLine(i); });`. Then compare with `Parallel.For(0, 25, i => { Console.WriteLine(/* reversed: */ 25 - i); });`

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen Good example, I will include it.

Comment: Ok, so if i should be "sorted", I should not use Parallel.For. Thx

Comment: Also try re-running my example many times. On my machine, the resulting sequence varies wildly. Sometimes it's in complete order, sometimes it's totally dis-ordered.

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen: For a large starting value (e.g. int.MaxValue given in the OP's question), the numbers will be semi-ordered at least at the start of the run.  That can have advantages e.g. in terms of having related memory be present in the CPU cache or an IO cache because a nearby thread just loaded it.  Of course the values will drift apart.  The more variant the cost of processing the loop body, the faster the values will drift.

Comment: @EricJ. I think you're right in many cases. In the current implementationm that is. But as one can see from the quote above, there's no guarantee they won't change that. But I think it's alright to use your trick `int derivedIndex = Int32.MaxValue - 1 - i;` for performance reasons only (and one should of course measure if it helps).

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen: If locality is really important, I would actually organize things so that each thread acts on its own queue of items that in turn are hopefully close together in RAM / on disk.  I'm just observing that you may get some *incidental* performance improvement from the loose ordering in this example.

Answer (score 1):

No, but you can certainly create a derived index from the loop counter

```
Parallel.For(0, Int32.MaxValue, (i) => 
{ 
    int derivedIndex = Int32.MaxValue - i;
});
```

Comment: It doesn't make much sense! The iterations run in parallel. There's no saying whether high or low values of `i` will come first. Try this: `Parallel.For(0, 25, i => { Console.WriteLine(i); });`

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen: Sure they will probably not run in order.  However, they will start at one extreme and move toward the other.  Depending on what happens in the loop, this may be beneficial.  For example, the semi-orderedness may cause data to *tend* to be in CPU cache or in a disk / disk controller cache since related, nearby data was recently fetched by another thread.

Answer (score 0):

```
....
int nTot = aRwRemove.Count - 1;
Parallel.For( 0, nTot, i =>
    {
        aRwRemove[nTot - i].Delete();
    }
);
----
```

Answer (score -2):

Easible achieved by calculating the decreasing value within the for loop.

```
for (int j = 0; j < Int32.MaxValue; j++)
{
    var i = Int32.MaxValue - j;
    // do something...
}
```

Comment: This is an ordinary for-loop and you could write `j--` here. But we talked about `Parallel.For`.